# Conjugated deoxyribonucleotides

Tags: molecular-biology, dna, pcr

I'm currently learning about using PCR techniques to make fluorescently labelled DNA probes, and the textbook mentions "**conjugated deoxyribonucleotides**"

Can someone explain what these are? Nothing too in-depth and detailed. Just a decent description/explanation so I can get somewhat of an understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "conjugate" means to join or couple something together. Deoxyribonucleotides are the "letters" of DNA - A, T, C, and G. In biology/biochemistry, when you conjugate something you chemically modify it by adding something to it. Given the context of your question, the conjugated deoxyribonucleotides are fluorescently-labeled — a fluorescent dye has been covalently attached to it.